# Derby foreign key constraint issue

Tags: sql, derby

Hi I am stuck with a foreign key constraint in my derby embedded table. I have three tables namely rooms, packages and reservation.

Room Table---
RoomId | RoomName| Rent | Description

Packages Table ---
pkgId | Name | Rate | Details

Reservation Table---
Id | GuestID | pkgId | RoomId | ChkIn | ChkOut | Date |

So the three foreign keys in Reservation tables are GuestID, pkgId and roomId.

All I wanted is the foreign keys to accept some values that is not in their respective tables. For example I want to make pkgId in reservation table to be 0 if a guest is not taking packages. But some reason I am getting error " UPDATE on table 'RESERVATION' caused a violation of foreign key constraint .. for key (0)". Is that because the 0 is not a value in Packages table ? Strangely enough it was not an issue with my earlier application. Did derby changed something with new jar files ? Or how can I solve this issue ? I want both RoomId and pkgId accept 0 in reservation table at some point of time while keeping the foreign key constraint. Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either insert new record into Packages Table => `insert into Packages( pkgid, name) values (0, 'guest is not taking packages' )` or remove the foreign key or use NULL value. The foreign key is a constraint that says "foreign key value **must always** exist in the referenced table".

Comment: I think I will go with inserting a new row and hide that row from end user. But I am not sure how it was working in my earlier derby versions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in SQL, 0 is a valid value just like any other. therefor if you set 0 as an FK column, it will look for a row with 0 on the related table.

If you want to indicate that there is no related row on the other table, you should use `null` as the ID

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot insert null value. But i was confused as the 0 value worked in my earlier derby version. Anyway thank you for confirming the fact.